javascript, cant get getElementsById to work
I have 2 fields in a web form to fill with text from the clipboard. I managed to get 1 to work but cant the other. I'm using a Chrome addon to autofill with javascript rule tried changing getElementsByName to getElementsById but doesn't work.
This code works:
<input id="repeatEmail" type="text" name="repeatEmail" autocomplete="chrome-off" maxlength="50" class="register__input" style="border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170) !important;">

setTimeout(async function GetClip() {
  let ctext = await window.navigator.clipboard.readText()
  console.log('Clipboard: ' + ctext);
  document.getElementsByName("repeatEmail")[0].value = ctext;
}, 1000)

This code doesn't work:
<input id="name" type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="28" class="register__input" style="border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170) !important;">

setTimeout(async function GetClip() {
  let ctext = await window.navigator.clipboard.readText()
  console.log('Clipboard: ' + ctext);
  document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value = ctext;
}, 1000)


For the first (working) element, you used the name attribute, that's why it works. The second one has id="name", so it has no name attribute, but an id. Either use name=... here as well or find the element using getElementById. (As IDs are to be unique, the result of the latter won't be an array, but the element itself.)

Also, take a look at a missing semi-colon. I didn't see a semi-colon after clipboard.read().

tried changing getElementsByName to getElementsById but doesn't work. that's because there is no such thing as getElementsById

@PauloSantos - missing ; are hardly ever an issue in javascript

On top of what Jaromanda X said, there is no such thing as getElementsById because you can't have multiple elements with the same id; ids must be unique.

@Jaromanda perhaps, but that's because you haven't suffered wasting hours trying to figure out why that damn pesky little bug is happening, only to realize that you missed a semi-colon somewhere that made the interpreter to misread a command and then.... Yeah, you get the picture. Good semi-colon discipline is VITAL.

@PauloSantos I agree - but the code in the question is not such a case :p

There isn't any attribute named 'name' in your code. getElementsByName looks for an attribute called 'name'. You need something like-


 let c = document.getElementsByName("name")[0];
 
 console.log(c)
<input id="name" name='name' type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="28" class="register__input" style="border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170) !important;">




try this
<input id="name" type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="28" class="register__input" style="border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170) !important;">


setTimeout(async function GetClip() {
    let ctext = await window.navigator.clipboard.readText()
    console.log('Clipboard: ' + ctext);
    document.getElementById("name").value = ctext;
  }, 1000)

you can't use getElementsById because id in element should be have 1 id (unique) and document.getElementsById is not a function so you must change getElementsById to getElementById

The second code doesn't work because there is no attribute called 'name' in the input, you can use getElementById instead of getElementsByName or use
document.querySelector('#name')

